# Cache Size Decorators in Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-decorators

I am building my own decorator function, but I can't seem to be able to update the **func.cache_length** method of the function.

The code below simply uses an OrderedDict to store the items from all the dataframes loaded in pandas, with 5 dataframes maximum stored in cache.

I want the user to also find out how many items currently the function has loaded using cache_length but every time I run it I get 0.

```
from functools import wraps
from collections import OrderedDict


def cache(func, max_length=5):
    
    func.cache_dict = OrderedDict()
    func.cache_length = 0
    @wraps(func)
    
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['df_name'] in func.cache_dict:
            return func.cache_dict[kwargs['df_name']]
        elif len(func.cache_dict) < max_length:
            print('Running function...')
            df = func(*args, **kwargs)
            func.cache_dict[kwargs['df_name']] = df
            func.cache_length += 1
            return df
        else:
            func.cache_dict.popitem(last=True)
            df = func(*args, **kwargs)
            func.cache_dict[kwargs['df_name']] = df
            return df
    
    func.cache_reset = lambda: func.cache_dict.clear()
        
    return wrapper


import pandas as pd


@cache
def data_reader(*, df_name: pd.DataFrame, file: str):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    return df
```

This is the output vs. expected (I should get 1),

```
data_reader(df_name='test_dataframe', file="parsed_data.csv")

>>

Running function...
....


>>

data_reader.cache_length

>>

0
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me, `data_reader.cache_length` should raise an attribute error since `data_reader` is the wrapper function you returned from your decorator.

Comment: there is no attribute error, check it.

Comment: Not sure, maybe `functool.wraps` is adding it, I wouldn't expect it, but I'm any case, the reason you aren't seeing `1` is because **nowhere** do you update `wrapper.cach_length`, you could check `data_reader.__wrapped__.cache_length`  though

Comment: Yes, as @juanpa.arrivillaga stated, you are checking the `cache_length` attribute of the `wrapper` object, not of the wrapped `func`. Regardless, this decorator seems relatively pointless, since it seems tailored to that specific function `data_reader` (the wrapper assumes a specific keyword argument). I would suggest either generalizing the decorator (if you want it to be reusable) or creating a class for your `data_reader` that has a `__call__` method and internally manages the cache on an instance level.

Comment: how would you generalize the decorator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you described, here is a more general implementation: (details below)

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
from functools import wraps


def cache(function=None, *, max_length=5):
    def decorator(func):
        cache_dict = OrderedDict()
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            call_repr = f"args={args}, kwargs={kwargs}"
            try:
                return cache_dict[call_repr]
            except KeyError:
                pass
            if len(cache_dict) >= max_length:
                cache_dict.popitem(last=False)
            print(f"Running function {func.__name__}...")
            cache_dict[call_repr] = output = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return output
        wrapper.cache = cache_dict
        return wrapper
    return decorator if function is None else decorator(function)


@cache(max_length=3)
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


def main():
    print(f"{add(1, 1)=}")                                  
    print(f"{add(2, 1)=}")
    print(f"{add(1, 1)=}")
    print(f"{add(3, 1)=}")
    print(f"{add(4, 1)=}")                                  
    print(f"{add(1, 1)=}")                                  
    print(f"{add.cache=}")
    add.cache.clear()
    print(f"{len(add.cache)=}")
    print(f"{add.cache=}")


if __name__ == "__main__":                                  
    main()
```

Output:

```
Running function add...
add(1, 1)=2
Running function add...
add(2, 1)=3
add(1, 1)=2
Running function add...
add(3, 1)=4
Running function add...
add(4, 1)=5
Running function add...
add(1, 1)=2
add.cache=OrderedDict([('args=(3, 1), kwargs={}', 4), ('args=(4, 1), kwargs={}', 5), ('args=(1, 1), kwargs={}', 2)])
len(add.cache)=0
add.cache=OrderedDict()
```

Notice the cache was used for the second `add(1, 1)` call, but not the third.

#### Details

- Uses the pattern allowing the decorator to be used with or without parantheses
- Resulting wrapper function has the `cache` attribute to allow direct access to the underlying `OrderedDict`
- Caching based on the string representation of all function arguments (positional and keyword)

#### Caveats

- Not *completely* general by any stretch
- Works as expected only with argument types that have a deterministic `__repr__` without side effects (which is what one would expect, to be fair)
- Cannot differentiate between arguments with identical string representations
- Clean type annotations may be a bit more involved

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you explain why do we need the outer function "cache"? Can we just keep decorator and wrapper?

Comment: @matt.aurelio The outer function is needed, if you want the ability to use the decorator _with_ and _without_ parantheses (and arguments), i.e. you can decorate functions like this `@cache` and also like this `@cache(max_length=10)`. This is a relatively common pattern for decorators with additional parameters, when all of them are optional. Just a little extra syntax-sugar.